# Using Rectangle to select text in iText

Tags: java, pdf, text, itext

This is an example from "iText in action" of using Rectangle to select a part of document to extract text from a pdf file:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdf);
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(txt));
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(70, 80, 420, 500);
RenderFilter filter = new RegionTextRenderFilter(rect);
TextExtractionStrategy strategy;
for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
    strategy = new FilteredTextRenderListener(
     new LocationTextExtractionStrategy(), filter);
     out.println(PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, i, strategy));
}
out.flush();
out.close();
```

What I don't understand is the meaning of these numbers (70, 80, 420, 500). Normally, (70, 80) is the coordinate, 420 is the width, 500 is the height of the rectangle, but I am not sure about the scale, how it's measured as well as the exact point where it start.
Could anyone explain it for me or show some example picture?

Comment: PDF defines a coordinate system for each page, the mediabox which you can request from the PdfReader. Very common is the origin located in the lower left corner and the unit being 1/72".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you have two coordinates: x = 70, y = 80 is the lower-left coordinate; x = 420, y = 500 is the upper-right coordinate. The unit used in PDF is the "user unit". By default, 1 user unit equals 1 point, but one can use the `/UserUnit` key to change the default. As mkl indicates in his comment, the MediaBox defines the page size. However, you can also have a CropBox that defines the visible area of the page (the CropBox should always be smaller than the MediaBox if present).